# Syncing changes to a fork of a fork

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-fork

I am working on an application on bitbucket which was forked later on to house special modules. This new fork, contained premium features. Now this fork was later on again forked for a certain country. Here is my diagram.

```
-- Core Application
    -- Premium Features
        -- Premium Features for a certain country
```

**Here is what i want:** Lets say i am working on "premium features". And after committing, i make a new changes to the "core application". I want this new change to be reflected all the way to "premium Features for a certain country".

Similarly if a new change has been made to "premium features" then it should only be added to "Premium Features for a certain country" and not to the "core application"

**Here is what i tried:** When inside premium features

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/user/core-application.git
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git rebase upstream/master
```

My Understanding was that this would pull all the code from core application into premium features and then rebase would redo the new changes to "premium features".

Comment: Your last sentence is correct (while you have to keep in mind that you are rewriting history. So if others use "Premium Features" repo too, they all have to recover from upstream rebase, or you should use merge instead of rebase). But actually you didn't state a question or problem or told us how the expected and actual behavior differ.

Comment: Thanks vampire, i just tired replacing rebase with merge and i think i am now starting to get a hang of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @vampire, i finally figured it out. So this is my new work flow now.

If there is a change to the core, i fetch and merge the change all the way up to the "Premium Features for a certain country". And if i make change to the "premium feature" fork then i just fetch and merge it in "Premium Features for a certain country".

I am not sure what happens if i dont merge the core change instantly and keep committing the "premium changes" but theoretically if there isn't a conflict in a file it should merge fine even after some commits.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple remotes inside your "Premium Features for a certain country" repo and pull from other remotes:

```
git remote add core-upstream https://github.com/user/core-application.git
git remote add premium-features-upstream https://github.com/user/core-application.git

git pull core-upstream master
git pull premium-features-upstream master
```